# How to use GET by id when id contains "/"

Tags: node.js, typescript, http-get, nodejs-server

I am working with Node.js and aws-sdk building an API so I have a **GET** function to download files by **ID** or **KEY**

```
export const downloadFile = async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: AWS_S3.Bucket,
    Key: req.params.key
  };

  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment');

  s3.getObject(params)
    .createReadStream()
    .on('error', error => {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Ocurrio un error al descargar el archivo',
        error
      });
    }).pipe(res);
}
```

The problem is about the name of the key because contains **/** and Node.js thinks that is a new Route.

Example:

```
const URL_API = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
const KEY = '/mendozarq/images/example.jpg'

const URL = `${URL_API}/download/${KEY}`;
```

Finaly I got this error:

```
Cannot GET /api/download//mendozarq/images/example.jpg
```

Comment: Remove the starting `/` from `key`: `const KEY = 'mendozarq/images/example.jpg'`

Comment: The solution was add "(*)" in my router like this router.route('/:key(*)')

Comment: replace / with a dash - or underscore _.